# Convert Html to PDF format

Tags: javascript

I can convert html to Pdf but the thing is now it cant display all information I want, I wish to display the location I searched using API google Map.

I have this in the controller

```
    public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
    {
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Select");
    }
```

and this link in my view

```
   <a href="GeneratePDF">Convert</a>
```

Comment: The `href` attribute for the link is neither a link nor an anchor. Additionally, the small amount of code that you've provided not only limits our knowledge of what you've done already, but also in what you're trying to do. Please update your question to provide more information.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information. What i did was i imported a nuget package named Rotativa and made an Action Named GeneratePDF and in my view it had the link which takes me to the generate pdf view but the problem is that it does not show me the google map when converted to pdf. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The HTML to PDF library that you used isn't able to generate static image from a javascript Google Map.

You shoud use **Static Maps API** to get the map as an image and include it inside your HTML.

The following example contains the URL of a static map image of downtown New York City:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794
```